# How to find the end-device causing high cpu usage in a Cisco switch?

Tags: cisco, switch, troubleshooting, network-core, port-security

While checking:

`sh proc cpu history`

there is high CPU utilization which occurs at a particular time.

Answer (score 4):

What is driving CPU usage in a Cisco switch is probably not a single end-device. Cisco switches can normally handle a full switching load without driving the CPU utilization unusually high. This is because the switching is largely handled in hardware.

The most likely cause is a service or protocol which the switch needs to handle in software. You didn't include the `show processes cpu` output, switch model, IOS version, and configuration. Without those, it is merely a guessing game.